# Php reg exp: Matching repeating pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to match strings like those below.

```
abc|q:1,f:2
cba|q:1,f:awd2,t:3awd,h:gr
```

I am using php and have tried both `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` with this expression.

```
/^([a-z]+)\|([a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+,?)+$/iU
```

This only returns the first part before the pipe, and one a:1. What am I doing wrong, why is it behaving this way and how can I make it work?

Comment: Realized I wasn't that clear on what output I was looking for. Something like ['cba', ['q':'1', 'f':'awd2', 't': '3awd', 'h': 'gr']] would be nice :)

Comment: As illustrated in SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888362/how-do-i-match-a-list-of-things-on-regex , you need two regex for decomposing a list. See also http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-regex1/ , `preg_split` can help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^([a-z]+)\|((?:[a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+,?)+)$/iU
```

would capture:

- the part before the pipe
- the part after the part

The greedy nature of the '+' [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) make your capturing group ([a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+,?) only capture the last set of characters matching this regex.

```
/(?ms)^((?:[a-z]+)\|(?:[a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+,?)+)$/iU
```

would capture the all line.

Note the '`?:`' to avoid [creating any capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Is there no way to get everything separated? So "cba|q:1,f:awd2,t:3awd,h:gr" becomes ['cba', ['q':'1', 'f':'awd2', 't': '3awd', 'h': 'gr']]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried:

```
<?php
$string = 'cba|q:1,f:awd2,t:3awd,h:gr';
$subpat = '[a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+';
$pat = "/^([a-z]+)\|($subpat(?:,$subpat)+)$/i";
preg_match( $pat, $string, $matches );
print_r( $matches );
?>
```

which yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => cba|q:1,f:awd2,t:3awd,h:gr
    [1] => cba
    [2] => q:1,f:awd2,t:3awd,h:gr
)
```

At this point you have the part before the vertical bar in `matches[1]` and the rest in `matches[2]`. The repetition of `$subpat` is there to ensure the strings to be properly separated by commas. After that, apply [explode](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) on `matches[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'cba|q:1,f:awd2,t:3awd,h:gr';

$re = '~(?:  ^(\w+)\| ) | (?: (\w+) : (\w+) (?:,|$) )~x';
preg_match_all($re, $string, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($m);
```

this will match the part before the pipe ("lead") and all key-value pairs at once. "lead" will be in `$m[0][1]` and key-values will be in `$m[1..x][2] and [3]`. Add some simple post-processing to convert this to a usable form, for example:

```
$lead = $m[0][1];
foreach(array_slice($m, 1) as $p)
    $data[$p[2]] = $p[3];
var_dump($lead, $data);
```