# Sequential (consecutive) new password with old password validation

Tags: php

How to validate sequential string/int when I want to change new password?
For example:

```
old pass: mypassword1
new pass: mypassword2
```

then it will return false, but if it's like this

```
old pass: mypassword1
new pass: mypassword3
```

then it will return true.

I've tried regEx method for the new password only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `If (end_number_of_previous + 1 == end_number_of_current) { return false; }else {return true;}`. Please, show us what you've tried so we can help in the specific problem...

Comment: @FirstOne i've tried regEx but it's only for the new password. have you tried comparing the old and new password with regEx? :)

Comment: Is your sequential part of the password always a number which added to the end of the password?

Comment: Can u share Regex code??

Comment: @Dinidu yeah, mostly

Comment: @devpro you can see it in here, i'm using this as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654157/php-reg-exp-matching-repeating-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
$oldpass = 'mypassword1';
$newpass = 'mypassword2';
preg_match('/^([^\d]+)([\d]*?)$/', $oldpass, $match);
$string = $match[1];
$number = $match[2] + 1;
$string .= $number;
$valid = $newpass === $string ? false : true;
var_dump($valid);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with passwords, you shouldn't be able to compare to a previous password (it should be securely hashed and therefore not reversible).  PHP has some excellent reading material on the topic [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

As an alternative, you could generate variations of the password that would be known to break your validation rules and then see if these match.

Lets assume you're using the password functions:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// AND....
password_verify($password, $hash);
```

Variations could look like:

```
$pwd = 'word1';
$num = substr($pwd,-1);
$invalid = false;
$phrase = substr($pwd, 0, -1);
foreach([$num++, $num--] as $variation) {
    if(password_verify($phrase.$variation, $hash)) {
        // password matches, the user is just incrementing the digit.
        $invalid = true;
    }
}
```

Therefore if `$invalid` is true then the password breaks your validation rule.

This is *not* a fool proof method. It is only as good as your ability to generate invalid password variations.

Comment: I need this for a change password module. and it's require the old password entry and new password entry from the html form. the form posts the old and new data to the function, not some hashed passwords. So, this is not what i am looking for. Thanks for the answer anyway. :)